# How can I put borders to my BottomNavigationBarItem elements?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have something like this.

[image]

But I don't know how to do it, I can't find any option related to the styles container of each tab.

```
    bottomNavigationBar:
        new BottomNavigationBar(items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
        title: new Text("Left"),
      ),
      new BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        title: new Text("Right"),
      ),
    ]),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *CustomPaint* wrapper your *BottomNavigationBar*

Define *CustomPainterBottomBar* extends from *CustomPainter* and set into *foregroundPainter* of *CustomPaint*

sample:

```
  bottomNavigationBar: CustomPaint(
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text("Left"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text("Left"),
          )
        ]
    ),
    foregroundPainter: CustomPainterBottomBar(),
  )
```

custom_painter_bottombar.dart

```
class CustomPainterBottomBar extends CustomPainter {
  static const TAG = 'CustomPainterBottombar';

  Paint paintLine = Paint()..color = Colors.green;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(size.width/2, 0), Offset(size.width/2, size.height), paintLine);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way

```
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    height: 60,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {})),
        VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Expanded(child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {}))
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Another example same your requirement

```
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    height: 60,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.home),
            Text("Left")
          ],
        )),
        VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Expanded(child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.home),
            Text("Right")
          ],
        )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Please find Sample code with click effects

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('AskNilesh'),
        centerTitle: false,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 60,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = 0;
                });
              },
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Left",
                    style: TextStyle(color: _selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )),
            VerticalDivider(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = 1;
                });
              },
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Right",
                    style: TextStyle(color: _selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.red : Colors.grey),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
          child: Text('Current Page $_selectedIndex'),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

You can check here on Dartpad  [BottomNavigationBarItem with borders](https://dartpad.dev/f800be9a39a7663c789606930a721757)

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to answer me, but if I do it the way you suggest, I lose the effects of the `BottomNavigationBarItem` so my question is about how to do it using` BottomNavigationBarItem`

Comment: @yavg if you want to add click then you can wrap your widget inside `Inkwell`

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this way, maybe can help you solve the problem, you still can have the effect of the ripple which you want from the navigationBar:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FieldBottomNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 50,
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                _IconButton(
                    iconData: Icons.home, iconTitle: 'Left', isLeft: true),
                _IconButton(iconData: Icons.search, iconTitle: 'Right')
              ]),
        ));
  }
}

class _IconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _IconButton({this.iconTitle, this.iconData, this.isLeft = false});

  final String iconTitle;
  final IconData iconData;
  final bool isLeft;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: isLeft
              ? Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 1))
              : null),
      child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(iconData, color: Colors.black, size: 24),
                  Text(iconTitle)
                ]),
          )),
    ));
  }
}
```